# bootstrap select получить элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть библиотека Bootstrap select .
нужно  получить событие unselect -   т е при снятии выделения нужно узнать на какой элемент был клик  не получиться отловить этот эвент  .
change - ловиться все ок  пытаюсь получтиь от туда  но для него  currentTarget  - это сам блок select. 
Мб кто сталкивался подскажите .Спасибо

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) работает c выпадающими списками. Что такое "снятие выделения"?

Answer (score 0):

onclick использовали ?
если `el` искомый селект

```
 el.onclick = (el)=>{console.log(el.value)}
```